# Moodle 3.11 - delete Activity - overwrite Confirm Dialog on module deletion

Tags: moodle

I have written an activity module for Moodle 3.11 and want to inform the manager, when deleting my module from the course, that user entries will be deleted as well.
At the moment, when the manager deletes my activity, there is a popup dialog (JavaScript) which says:
[Confirm Are you sure that you want to delete the My Activity "myactivity"?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn1aI.png)
String identifier for this dialog is (I hope I am right here): deletechecktypename

How can I overwrite this message with language strings?
Or how can I edit this dialog?

When I click Yes, the function myactivity_delete_instance(%id) in lib.php is called and here I can only check if all would go well and if not, cancel delete.

I cannot show any message here anymore. If I do, e.g. with:
\core\notification::error($my_error_msg);
It is shown not immediatly, only the next time that module page is loaded or reloaded.

But if I return false in myactivity_delete_instance, an error is thrown.

I would much like to either show some own details in that JS-Confirm Dialog, so the user (manager) can avoid deleting, or either a way to show that error core notification in my lib.php directly after deletion.

I searched the moodle documentation about these things, but without success.
I asked this already in the german section of the moodle developer forum: [Aktivität eines Kurses löschen - eigene Ja/Nein Bestätigung](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=451403) but I think this question is much too specific, my experience with the moodle forum is, that these type of questions are not answered.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need to do it programmaticaly.

You can go to your administration. On the main tab go to Language, choose Language customisation's link. Once you choose the language you want to edit the strings from, click on open language to edit (or something like that). Depending of your site it'll take a bit of time to load everything.

Once there you'll just have to target the plugin you want to ovrwrite the strings from.

Programmaticaly you can add a listener to the link / button that triggers this pop-up and launch your own pop up.
On the listener add the event to prevent it and on confirmation trigger the event.

It would give something like that (i use swal on my plugins. Maybe not the most efficient to bypass the moodle popup way, but i like it better to pass functions):

```
const btn = document.getElementById('theid');
btn.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                e.target.submit();
            }
        })
    });
```